# How to dynamically create a abstract class with custom members from the __construct method of other class?

Tags: php

I have a class TestController ...
The "TestController" Class extend an "AppBaseController" class that is part of o MVC framework ...

At some point int the "TestController" __construct() I need to dynamically create a abstract  class and add to this class some properties, Let's say that the new class is named "newClass" ...
Later on I need to include a "BasiClass" that extend this "newClass" ...

I hope you understand what I mean ...

Here is the code:

The TestController class look like this:

```
<?php

    // TestController.php

    Class TestController extend AppBaseController
    {

       public $property_1; // String
       public $property_2; // Array
       // ...
       public $property_3; // Object

       /* 

          There are also some properties declared in 
          AppBaseController that must be available in the 
          NewClass ...
          Let's say that one of them is named $property_4

       */


       public function __construct()
       {

          parent::__construct();

          // ... some code ...

             /*

              Dynamically create a Abstract class newClass HERE and
              add the the properties. 

             */

          // ... more code ...
       }


       public function Test()
       {

           include "BasiClass.php";
           $object = new BasicClass;

           echo $object->property_1;
           echo $object->property_2;
           echo $object->property_3;
           echo $object->property_4;


       }


    } // End TestController

?>
```

The BasiClass class look like this:

```
<?php

    // BasiClass.php

    Class BasiClass extend newClass
    {
       # This class extend dynamically created class newClass !!!

       public function __construct()
       {
          // ...

       }

    } // End BasiClass

?>
```

The idea is that the BasiClass to have the public members property_1,property_2,property_3, and property_4 because it's extending the newClass while newClass should be dynamically  created.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why does the entire class need to be created dynamically...?! Sounds like a pretty terrible idea for regular code.

Comment: Yes, I need to pass a lot of the methods from AppBaseController to this new Class ... The idea is to create a SuperModel Class dynamically ... I need to pass varibles like languages,current_language,is_logedin... from AppBaseController to this newClass and then use it ... I can't extend the AppBaseController directly because in the __constructor it's running code that I don't need in this newClass ...

Comment: Then... extend the controller class and **override the constructor**? Or maybe restructure your class hierarchy to extend classes sensibly in a hierarchy where only related classes are related?

Comment: Look The AppBaseController have a public variable called $language, and in the __construct() of this class I have $this->language = $current_language; So in the testController that extend AppBaseController I can use echo $this->language and prints out the current language. I need this language variable to be available in a ... let's call it AppBaseModel Class ... In this way I can develop in a separate class and keep The TestController code as clean as possible.

Comment: Imagine a small MVC Framework and with this I want to create a AppBaseModel that has almost the same variables like AppBaseController so when I need to make a new modelClass I extend this AppBaseModel ... I know that maybe sonds strange but ... I made a custom small MVC Framework and now I need to create a BaseModel with elements from BaseController.